# Connecting Attiny85 to nRF24IO1: How can I get 2 free IO pins in attiny85

Tags: nrf24l01, attiny85

I am trying to connect an Attiny85 to an nRF24L01. I tried the library NRFlite from the Arduino IDE libraries and it works fine. The problem is that I end up with only 1 free analog pin (pin 4) in Attiny85 (see below). However, I need 2 free pins.

```
Radio  --  ATtiny85

CE    ->  Pin 3  
   
CSN   ->  Pin  3         

MOSI  ->  Pin 1 

MISO  ->  Pin 0

SCK   ->  Pin 2

IRQ   -> No connection

VCC   -> No more than 3.6 volts

GND   -> GND
```

I remember reading an article sometime ago about this same issue, but I cannot find it or remember any detail...

Any help is appreciated.

Zak

Comment: Free pins to do what? Digital in? Digital out? Analog?

Comment: You can try this http://nerdralph.blogspot.com/2015/05/nrf24l01-control-with-2-mcu-pins-using.html?m=1

Comment: Thank you very much. That was what I was looking for. I will give it a try.

Comment: I just tried this: https://github.com/dparson55/NRFLite which uses nerdralph's blog. It is working.